# Prevent Rake's sh command from echoing the command

Tags: ruby, rake

Whenever I call sh from rake it often echos the command that will be ran right before it is run. How can I prevent sh from logging the commands to stdout. I'd like to prevent this as I have api keys in the command I am calling, and I don't want to expose them in my build log.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do with with Rake's `sh`. A better option might be to store your API keys in environment variables.

Comment: @Jordan I would do that except I am calling a shell tool, that only takes in args and not env vars, and I have no control over the code of said tool.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two parts to solving this. The first is to pass the `verbose: false` option, which will prevent the command from being printed before it's executed:

```
$ cat Rakefile
SECRET = 'foobarbaz'

task :foo do
  sh "echo #{SECRET} > secrets.txt", verbose: false
end

$ rake foo
(no output)
```

However, this doesn't help if there's an error, since Rake will print the failed command if it returns an error:

```
$ cat Rakefile
SECRET = 'foobarbaz'

task :foo do
  sh "echo #{SECRET} > secrets.txt; exit 1", verbose: false
end

$ rake foo
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [echo foobarbaz > secrets.txt; exit 1...]
...
```

The solution is hinted at [in the docs for `sh`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-i-sh):

> If a block is given, upon command completion the block is called with an OK flag (true on a zero exit status) and a Process::Status object. Without a block a RuntimeError is raised when the command exits non-zero.

You can see where the default behavior comes from [in the Rake source](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/1b27eb2f8234190bba0e973194d38bcf09443ec0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb#L67-L71). The solution, then, is to supply our own block:

```
$ cat Rakefile
SECRET = "foobarbaz"

task :foo do
  sh "echo #{SECRET} > secrets.txt; exit 1", verbose: false do |ok, status|
    unless ok
      fail "Command failed with status (#{status.exitstatus}): [command hidden]"
    end
  end
end

$ rake foo
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [command hidden]
...
```

Looks good!

If you find yourself needing this in multiple places, you could write a convenience method; something like this:

```
def quiet_sh(*cmd)
  options = (Hash === cmd.last) ? cmd.pop : {}
  options = { verbose: false }.merge(options)

  sh *cmd, options do |ok, status|
    unless ok
      fail "Command failed with status (#{status.exitstatus}): [command hidden]"
    end
  end
end

SECRET = "foobarbaz"

task :foo do
  quiet_sh "do_secret_things"
end
```

Comment: You can also set the verbose flag globally with `Rake::FileUtilsExt.verbose_flag =`